# Django fixture not loading with loaddata

Tags: django, fixtures, loaddata

I've created a json fixture, and put it in my myapp/fixtures/. I've added myapp/fixtures to settings.FIXTURE_DIRS.
Here's the output of my attempt to load the fixture:

```
jeff@jeff-linux:~/myapp$ ./manage.py loaddata --verbosity=2 default.json
Loading 'default' fixtures...
[...truncated checking default paths and installed apps/fixtures...]
Checking '/home/jeff/myapp/fixtures/' for fixtures...
Trying '/home/jeff/myapp/fixtures/' for default.json fixture 'default'...
No json fixture 'default' in '/home/jeff/myapp/fixtures/'.
Trying '/home/jeff/myapp/fixtures/' for default.json.gz fixture 'default'...
No json fixture 'default' in '/home/jeff/myapp/fixtures/'.
Trying '/home/jeff/myapp/fixtures/' for default.json.zip fixture 'default'...
No json fixture 'default' in '/home/jeff/myapp/fixtures/'.
Trying '/home/jeff/myapp/fixtures/' for default.json.bz2 fixture 'default'...
No json fixture 'default' in '/home/jeff/myapp/fixtures/'.
Checking absolute path for fixtures...
Trying absolute path for default.json fixture 'default'...
No json fixture 'default' in absolute path.
Trying absolute path for default.json.gz fixture 'default'...
No json fixture 'default' in absolute path.
Trying absolute path for default.json.zip fixture 'default'...
No json fixture 'default' in absolute path.
Trying absolute path for default.json.bz2 fixture 'default'...
No json fixture 'default' in absolute path.
No fixtures found.
jeff@jeff-linux:~/myapp$ ls fixtures/
defaults.json  moneytrail.json
```

here's what's in default.json:
[
 {
  "pk": 1,
  "model": "myapp.feature",
  "fields": {
   "default_feature": "0.25"
  }
 }
]

Am I missing something obvious here? I've tried the FIXTURE_DIRS as both fixtures and fixtures/ same results.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your file: `defaults.json`

Your command line argument: `default.json`

Look closely.

Comment: Damn it. Time to give up programming and go do construction.

Comment: Stick with programming. A mistake like that could cause a house to collapse!